# Have been trying to add migration to my project in ASP.NET MVC using C# but am getting these errors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
>
> Possible reasons for this include:
>
> - You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
> - You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
> - You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

Comment: Did you install the tool using `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

Answer (score 0):

Do you use VSCode on linux ?
If this is the case, you have to add the dotnet/tools path.
You can also check if your tool is in the folder.

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
```